# SQL query to fetch unmatched records from two tables

Tags: sql, select, join

I have two tables `userprofile` and `deviceid`.

- `userprofile` contains columns `username`, `studentname`
- `deviceid` contains columns `username`, `device id`

I want to fetch username records from `userprofile` which are not in `deviceid` (`username`).

My query is

```
SELECT 
    userprofile.username, userprofile.studentname 
FROM 
    userprofile
LEFT JOIN 
    deviceid ON deviceid.username = userprofile.username
WHERE 
    deviceid.username IS NULL;
```

It's not fetching any values.

Comment: Can you show sample data?

Answer (score 3):

Your wording was actually the exact way to go:

> I want to fetch username records from userprofile which are not in deviceid(username)

Now, we just need to put this in to SQL:

```
SELECT username 
FROM   userprofile
WHERE  username NOT IN (SELECT username FROM deviceid)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I usually do it

```
select * from userprofile a where not exists (select 1 from device b where a.username = b.username)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost near to the solution

```
SELECT userprofile.username,userprofile.studentname FROM userprofile
  LEFT OUTER JOIN deviceid ON deviceid.username = userprofile.username
  WHERE deviceid.username IS NULL;
UNOIN ALL
SELECT userprofile.username,userprofile.studentname FROM deviceid
  LEFT OUTER JOIN userprofile ON deviceid.username = userprofile.username
  WHERE deviceid.username IS NULL;
```

for other type of solution Try this [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ffa1/6)

Hope this may useful

Comment: This is much more complicated than necessary.

Answer (score 0):

In your query, you are filtering on a left joined table in your where clause.  That changes the left join to an inner join.  To use your approach, do your filtering in the join clause.  In your specific case, all you have to do is change the word "where" to "and".

Mureinik's answer will also work, but might be slow.  Hans Kilian's answer will also work.

Answer (score 0):

you need to fetch the values in userprofile then try the following code

```
select username,studentname
from userprofile 
where upper(username) not in (select upper(username) from deviceid);
```

the above query is in **Oracle**.It will returns the details of userprifile which are not in deviceid